# Is there anyway to pre-download a game Xbox One

Tags: xbox-one, xbox-network

I own an Xbox one and I was wondering if it’s possible to download a game before you make the initial purchase. For example, to save having to downloading the game you’re getting next week, you can download it now so it’s ready to play as soon as you buy it. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no direct way to do what you want.  However, if a game has a trial download, you might be able to download that, and when you go to purchase the game, it will use the files already downloaded via the trial.

Next to the "Buy" button is the free trial button.  Not all games will have this option.

[image: Free Trial image]

Other than that, some games that are purchasable for pre-order, you should be able to pre-download.